# Website url with or without www to reduce wait time during page load

Tags: wordpress, web

I have a Wordpress site. I see in pingdom tools test that if my site url has www and user types the URL without www, then he/she is forced to wait. And the wait time is affecting my page ranking. Can anyone help me with the following questions:

1. Which URL is better for higher page ranking, with www or without www?
2. Is it possible to redirect my user to my site without having to wait i.e, whether www is used or not redirect to my page? And if yes, then how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [google webmaster tools1](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) there you will find many answers of your questions.

tl;dr: you could set up prime address there and tell google what to index first www or without www!